# How to associate a field in a form to a specific value in a table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm new at VBA programming. So I have a table that contains 'ID' and 'Bidder' and a form that has one field 'Text1',
I'm trying to make my field display the 'Bidder' value where 'ID'=2.

I was thinking I could make a query and store the value in the field, not sure if I can do that,

```
Text1.Value= DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT Bidder FROM Bidder_v3 where (([ID])='2')"
```

is now working, probably a bad idea, but I don't really know how to solve this one.

I would really appreciate some help. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display a single value then you could use the [DLOOKUP function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/dlookup-function-HA001228825.aspx)

```
Text1.Value= DLOOKUP("Bidder_vs","[Bidder]","[ID]='2'")
```

---

This is okay for a single value but, preferably, the Form would be based on a query that retrieves the data you need to display.

Note that `DoCmd.RunSql` doesn't return anything, it is designed to execute action-queries, such as UPDATE queries.

Answer (score 0):

These two queries have the same result, and will return Bidder from the first record in the recordset.

```
Text1.Value = 
CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Bidder_v3 where ID='2'")("Bidder")
```

and

```
Text1.Value = 
CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Bidder FROM Bidder_v3 where ID='2'")(0)
```

BTW: I suspect the ID field is a number and `ID = '2'` can be changed to `ID = 2`.